# How to emit bare XML for a [WebGet] method in WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, xml-serialization

How can I define a [OperationContract] [WebGet] method to return XML that is stored in a string, without HTML encoding the string?

The application is using WCF service to return XML/XHTML content which has been stored as a string. The XML does not correspond to any specific class via [DataContract]. It is meant to be consumed by an XSLT.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
public XmlContent GetContent()
{
   return new XmlContent("<p>given content</p>");
}
```

I have this class:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class XmlContent : IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlContent(string content)
    {
        this.Content = content;
    }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {

        writer.WriteRaw(this.Content);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

But when serialized, there is a root tag the wraps the given content.

```
<XmlContent>
  <p>given content</p>
</XmlContent>
```

I know how to change the name of the root tag ([XmlRoot(ElementName = "div")]), but I need to omit the root tag, if at all possible.

I have also tried [DataContract] instead of IXmlSerializable, but it seems less flexible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Return an XmlElement.  You don't need IXmlSerializable.  You don't need a wrapper class.

example service interface:

```
namespace Cheeso.Samples.Webservices._2009Jun01
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace="urn:Cheeso.Samples.Webservices" )]
    public interface IWebGetService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                    UriTemplate = "/Greet/{greeting}")]
        XmlElement Greet(String greeting);
    }
}
```

service implementation:

```
namespace Cheeso.Samples.Webservices._2009Jun01
{
    [ServiceBehavior(Name="WcfWebGetService",
                     Namespace="urn:Cheeso.Samples.WebServices",
                     IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]

    public class WcfWebGetService : IWebGetService
    {
        public XmlElement Greet (String greeting)
        {
            string rawXml = "<p>Stuff here</p>";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(rawXml));
            return doc.DocumentElement;
        }
    }
}
```

See also, this similar question, but without the WebGet twist:
[serializing-generic-xml-data-across-wcf-web-service-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935080/serializing-generic-xml-data-across-wcf-web-service-requests).

Comment: Thanks! That works, but does have the downside of deserializing the XML and then re-serializing it. Not as efficient as I would like, but at least it eliminates the root tag. Thanks for the alternative.

Comment: Yup, I think if your original data is stored as a string, you have to go through that multi-step process.  If it is just static strings, you could de-ser only once and then cache the result.  Supposing it is a template that you fill in for the final document fragment - you could cache the template and fill in the dynamic bits with each request.

Comment: using this example with mono 2.10.8.1 throws - Exception Type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' cannot have a DataContract attribute Name set to null or empty string.

Comment: On mono I found returning a Stream worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132281/return-raw-string-from-rest-service-method