# Passing an Xml from a Web Service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xmldocument, invalidoperationexception

I have a web service which returns something of type `MyData`.

```
 public class MyData
 {
        public string Name;
        [XmlElement("item")]
        public Object[] DataItems;
 }
```

I have used `Object[]` for `DataItems` because the type of array could be of several types. I have two different classes which I could successfully send using this method. See below.

`clientResults` is the filled DataSet.

```
MyData returnResult = new MyData();

MyFirstClass[] resultData = new MyFirstClass[clientResults.Tables[0].Rows.Count];

resultData.MyFirstClassProperty1 = "Blah Blah";
resultData.MyFirstClassProperty2 = "Blah Blah";

returnResult.DataItems = resultData.
```

I could easily change `MyFirstClass` to `MySecondClass` and set its own properties and the web service would properly serialize both the classes and every one was happy!

However now there is a need where I have to pass an XML returned by the `DataSet.GetXml()` function.

Naturally, what I did was

```
 XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
 xdoc.LoadXml(clientResults.GetXml());
 resultData.DataItems = new XmlDocument[] { xdoc };
```

But this is throwing an exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.Xml.XmlDocument may not be used in this context.
```

So what I thought, ok lets try it with XmlNode.

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(clientResults.GetXml());
XmlNode xElement = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/");
result.DataItems = new XmlNode[] { xElement };
```

Still its throwing the SAME exception. What could be wrong?

How do I properly pass an XML through a web service?

Comment: have you checked what throws the exception?
xdoc.LoadXml or clientResults.GetXml()

Comment: None of them. Its the XML Serialization that throws the exception. I can paste the stack trace if it is important.

Comment: maybe the following two like can be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935080/serializing-generic-xml-data-across-wcf-web-service-requests http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/6ff9c882-f353-4ad5-816a-7fa9f424bc6c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty easy. All I had to do was create a parent class which other classes were going to inherit from.

```
public class BaseData
{

}

public class XmlData : BaseData
{
   public XmlNode xml;
}
```

And I made the `Object[]` to a `BaseData[]`.

```
public class MyData
 {
        public string Name;
        [XmlElement("item")]
        public BaseData[] DataItems;
 }
```

And then I selected the node using XPath and assigned it.

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(clientResults.GetXml());
XmlNode xElement = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/");

XmlData[] xmlData = new XmlData[1];
xmlData[0] = new XmlData();
xmlData[0].xml = xElement;

result.DataItems = xmlData;
```

I also had to put a `XmlInclude(typeof(XmlData))` to the web service method signature.

And it was working perfectly!

Comment: I tried your source and I must be missing something... I get the following error on the attribute from block 2:  'System.Xml.XmlElement' is not an attribute class -- any ideas?

Comment: You should have a using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute I guess. Take a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx)